# Vue.js 2.x - Vuetify 2.6.4 - v-data-table v-text-field Validation rules applied to sum of values of multiple fields

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I need to validate the `size of a box` and have 3 fields:

`Width`, `Length` and `Height`

I solved as per this [codepen](https://codepen.io/vue_js/pen/PoEwvpv)

Now I have to add a further rule: "`sum of sides`"
i.e: the sum of `Width + Length + Height`

I create the variable containing the limits:

```
sos:{"min":20,"max":45},
```

But I really do not have any Idea of how apply to the project keeping the same structure..

Can somebody suggest the right Direction?

Thanks

Comment: Did you work with computed properties in Vue?

Comment: Do you really need to have the limits inside a variable? You can create a single validation rule and use it in multiple `v-text-field`

Comment: @gguney yes, sure, but I would not know how apply to this case, unless fully changing the structure of the rules.

Comment: @cmfc31 limits in the example are in a variable but these changes according to the carrier, therefore  are collected from the database via ajax call.